# Minimization of function under constraints in R

Tags: r, optimization, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a function "f" as follows:

```
f <- function (X){
  DD= 91.8372-10.3096*(as.numeric((X[1]<70.5)&(X[2]>69.5)&(X[2]<79.5)&(X[3]>37.5)))
          +5.3719*(as.numeric((X[1]>68.5)&(X[2]<47.0)))
          -4.8144*(as.numeric((X[1]<73.5)&(X[2]<79.5)&(X[3]>36.5)))
          +3.9302*(as.numeric((X[2]<79.5)&(X[3]>45.5)&(X[3]<51.5)))-4.9666*(as.numeric(X[2]<71.5))
          - 5.8016*(as.numeric((X[1]>75.5)&(X[1]<83.5)&(X[2]<76.5)&(X[3]>36.5)&(X[3]<51.5)))
          +9.7572*(as.numeric((X[1]>68.5)&(X[1]>73.5)&(X[2]>71.5)&(X[2]>75.0)&(X[2]>76.5)& 
          X[2]>79.5)))+4.2909*(as.numeric((X[1]>68.5)&(X[2]>75.0)&(X[3]<36.5)&(X[3]<39.5)&(X[3] 
          <45.5)))+17.6214*(as.numeric(X[1]>89.0))
```

This function has three variables X1 (X[1]),X2 (X[2]) and X3 (X[3]). So, my question is how to find/optimize these variables in R in such a way by applying these variables the result of the function "f" will be greater or equal certain value let say 96.

Comment: Have you already looked at function like `optim` in R?

Comment: The way this is formulated makes the problem nondifferentiable. Most solvers will have problems with this.

Comment: Multiplying by a logical converts it to numeric so `as.numeric` is not needed.

Comment: Hi  MrFlick , I tried to optimize a function (96-f)^2 but the problem is that this function will be already less than 96. And using ` optim`  does not allow to apply a constraint that the f >=96.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach :

```
f <- function(X)
{
  DD <-  ((91.8372 - 10.3096 * (as.numeric((X[1] < 70.5) & (X[2] > 69.5) & (X[2] < 79.5) & (X[3] > 37.5)))
          + 5.3719 * (as.numeric((X[1] > 68.5) & (X[2] < 47.0)))
          - 4.8144 * (as.numeric((X[1] < 73.5) & (X[2] < 79.5) & (X[3] > 36.5)))
          + 3.9302 * (as.numeric((X[2] < 79.5) & (X[3] > 45.5) & (X[3] < 51.5))) - 4.9666 * (as.numeric(X[2]  < 71.5))
          - 5.8016 * (as.numeric((X[1] > 75.5) & (X[1] < 83.5) & (X[2] < 76.5) & (X[3] > 36.5) & (X[3] < 51.5)))
          + 9.7572 * (as.numeric((X[1] > 68.5) & (X[1] > 73.5) & (X[2] > 71.5) & (X[2] > 75.0) & (X[2] > 76.5) & X[2] > 79.5)))
          + 4.2909 * (as.numeric((X[1] > 68.5) & (X[2] > 75.0) & (X[3] < 36.5) & (X[3] < 39.5) & (X[3] < 45.5))) 
          + 17.6214 * (as.numeric(X[1] > 89.0)))
  
  if(DD < 96)
  {
    return(10 ^ 30)
    
  }else
  {
    return(DD)
  }
}

library(DEoptim)

obj_DEoptim <- DEoptim(fn = f, lower = rep(-1000, 3), upper = rep(1000, 3), control = list(itermax = 1000))

obj_DEoptim$optim$bestmem
  
  par1       par2       par3 
  73.02648  251.92860 -976.23650

obj_DEoptim$optim$bestval

  96.1281
```